# Cascading DropDownList is not firing anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax, cascadingdropdown

I have these DropDownLists:

```
<li>
    <label>State:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" Width="356px"
        DataTextField="State" DataValueField="StateId" />
    <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlState" TargetControlID="ddlState" PromptText="State"
        PromptValue="" ServicePath="~/Forms/General/DropWS.asmx" ServiceMethod="getState" runat="server"
        Category="StateProvider" LoadingText="Loading..." />
</li>
<li>
    <label>City:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" Width="356px" DataTextField="City" DataValueField="CityId" />
    <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlCity" TargetControlID="ddlCity" PromptText="City"
        PromptValue="" ServicePath="~/Forms/General/DropWS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCity" runat="server"
        Category="CityProvider" ParentControlID="ddlState" LoadingText="Loading..." />
</li>
```

The first dropdown already starts filled with the States.

I also created the WebService to get the data. It is working because I debbuged the webservice and it gave me the XML with the correct data.

But when I run the program, I can select any State that nothing happens, the Cities are not being populated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If u r getting Correct in XML file then the problem is that point where you append that data
>
> few steps...
>
> 1. Run your program
>
>    2. right click on screen select inspect Element
>    3. click on "Console"
>    4. there should be an error on the event where u append data

Comment: The error is here: Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined" ... 
Maybe something wrong with: $create(Sys.Extended.UI.CascadingDropDownBehavior

Answer (score 1):

Now it is working...

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined"

was fixed by replacing:

> `<asp:ScriptManager> with <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>`